# In Excel, is there a simple way to extract data fields from a set of records into a table so I can graph the data?

Tags: excel, database, powerquery, m

I've recorded some data from my car using an 'on-board diagnostics' reader and copied the data into Excel.  It appears as the image below.

**Raw data**

[image: Raw data]

I'm trying to find a simple way to read data fields from each record into a simple table (as image below) so I can plot the data.

I tried (and failed) with pivot tables, but then managed to create the table below using 'power query' and some manual steps.  But his would not be practical for the larger data runs I want to make.

**Power Query and lots of messing**

[image: Power Query and lots of messing]

Is there some simple way in Excel just to read data from records in this type of input format into a table?  My guess is there must be but I'm missing something somewhere?  I'd prefer not to have to resort to VBA.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why would PQ not be "practical"? It's a relatively simple query depending on your data connection to whatever output your reader provides.

Comment: Hi Ron, output from the reader is just a data dump which I copied into Excel.  You can't query the reader so I wasa hoping for some way to treat the dump as a pile of data records I could query.  I will be collecting different sets of parameters so solution should be generic.  My comment that the method I used wasn't practical was aimed at the manual steps between the PQ steps, not PQ.  The datasets will have hundreds of records each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula (Bxxxx the last value in column B)

```
=CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(B1:Bxxxx,7),4,6,2)
```

and in the next right cell

```
=x2/100
```

where x is the LOAD_PCT column of the result.

**Older version**

Suppose the raw datas are in columns A:C, place this formula in D2,E2,F2 and adjust the range B1:B62 as required.

D2 `=INDEX($B$1:$B$62,4+(ROW()-ROW($D$2))*7,0)`

E2 `=INDEX($B$1:$B$62,6+(ROW()-ROW($D$2))*7,0)`

F2 `=INDEX($B$1:$B$62,2+(ROW()-ROW($D$2))*7,0)`

and copy down them.

[image]

Comment: That looks like it will do exactly what I want  .... but unfortunately I'm using Office Professional Plus 2021 and these functions are only available in Office 365

Comment: @johnb Pls. find the supplement in the post.

Comment: Many thanks Black cat.  That does the job and should be easy to amend for different size records as well.  I'd never have come up with that!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use Power Query, and wanted it to be dynamic,I'd suggest a flow like:

- Copy the data to Excel as you do now
- Format it as a `Table` with a defined Name

  - This could be done using VBA
- Run the following PQ routine

  - Could be triggered by the same VBA routine that created the table
  - if so the VBA routine could pass the Table name as a parameter, if it will not be the same each time
- Note that the PQ routine includes a calculated column since you seem to show one in your output from the input.
- You could conditionally add multiple calculated columns using `List.Accumulate` if need be.
- Also note that none of the final column names are hard-coded (except for the desired order list, which should include a list of all possible columns in the desired order. If the columns are not present, they will be ignored in the final table).
- The initial names (`Column1` ...) are hard coded since this is what is generated by the `Format as Table` function, but those could be made dynamic also, if necessary.
- Also note the routine where all columns are set to `type number`. You could change this if you needed different types for different columns.

```
let

//change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],

//Table should always have three columns: Parameter, Units, Unit type
//Don't need/want the unit type column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Column3"}),

//Remove the rows that mark the start of a data set    
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Column2] <> null and [Column2] <> "of")),

//group by each type of data
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Column1"}, {
        {"all", each _, type table [Column1=text, Column2=number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Column1"}),

//table types record
    #"Table Types" = 
        let 
            columnNames = List.Transform(#"Removed Columns1"[all], each _{0}[Column1]),
            columnTypes = List.Repeat({type number}, List.Count(columnNames)),
            rowColumnTypes = List.Transform(columnTypes, (t) => [Type = t, Optional = false]),
            rowType = Type.ForRecord(Record.FromList(rowColumnTypes, columnNames), false)
        in 
            rowType,

//Add a column which shows table of data
// for each data type
    #"New Table" = Table.FromColumns(
            List.Accumulate(
                #"Removed Columns1"[all],
                {},
                (s,c)=> s & {c[Column2]}),
                type table #"Table Types"),


//Conditionally add LOAD column
//if you might have other conditionally added columns,
//  you can do that with the List.Accumulate function
    #"Add Load Column" = if List.Contains(Table.ColumnNames(#"New Table"),"LOAD_PCT") 
        then Table.AddColumn(#"New Table","LOAD", each [LOAD_PCT] / 100, type number)
        else #"New Table",

//Arrange columns in Desired order
    #"Col Order" = {"RPM","MAF","TT","XX","LOAD_PCT","LOAD","ZZZ","XXX","continue with all possible columns"},
    #"Ordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Add Load Column",#"Col Order",MissingField.Ignore)
            
in
    #"Ordered Columns"
```

***Your data after creating `Table`***
[image]

***Result***
[image]

Comment: Many thanks Ron.  This was a bit(lot) beyond my current level with PQ but I managed to figure it out and get it working.  I'll need to revisit I think to improve my knowledge so I can adapt the query if required, but for longer term this looks like a good solution.        I don't know if I'm supposed to accept more than 1 solution but I have because both solved my problem.

Comment: @johnb I believe you can only "accept" one solution (although you can upvote multiple solutions) and the one you accept should be the one you consider to be the best. Take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data and columns supplied, the below could potentially work.

Again this assumes that you dump the raw data into Excel as now. And then convert this range into a table (by pressing CTRL + T ) without header names.

```
  let
   Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

   // Remove record info lines and null lines
   FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column1] <> null) and ([Column2] <> "of")),

   // Remove unnecessary column (only contains the Units)
   RemoveCol = Table.RemoveColumns(FilteredRows,{"Column3"}),

   // Add an Index column
   AddIndexCol = Table.AddIndexColumn(RemoveCol, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

   // Pivot Column 1 using Column 2 as the Values column and Aggregation = 'Don't Aggregate'
   PivotColumn = Table.Pivot(AddIndexCol, List.Distinct(AddIndexCol[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2"),

   // Convert Index Column to a Modulo column (resets to 0 every 3 rows) 
   AddModuloCol = Table.TransformColumns(PivotColumn, {{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, 3), type number}}),

   // Fill down the values in the Load_PCT, RPM & MAF columns
   FillDown = Table.FillDown(AddModuloCol,{"LOAD_PCT", "RPM", "MAF"}),

   // Filter out rows with nulls in any of those 3 columns
   SelectFullRowOnly = Table.SelectRows(FillDown, each ([Index] = 2) ),

   // Remove Index column
   RemoveIndexCol = Table.RemoveColumns(SelectFullRowOnly,{"Index"}),

   // Reorder columns to match requested output table
   ReorderCols = Table.ReorderColumns(RemoveIndexCol,{"RPM", "MAF", "LOAD_PCT"}),

   // Change column types to decimal numbers
   ChangeColTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ReorderCols,{{"LOAD_PCT", type number}, {"MAF", type number}, {"RPM", type number}}),

   // Add calculated column - which divides the LOAD_PCT value by 100 for each row
   AddCalcCol = Table.AddColumn(ChangeColTypes, "Load", each [LOAD_PCT] / 100, type number)   
in
   AddCalcCol
```

This takes the table data and pivots it around an index column so that the 3 different attributes are now in their own column and then uses the concept of modulo to fill each of these columns for each record.

When the pivot is done on Column 1, remember to change the default 'Sum' operation on Column 2 to 'Don't Aggregate':
[Pivot Sub Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epzg1.png)

Comment: Thanks Hanesy.  That works too.  I'm starting to understand PQ a little better with your and Ron's inputs.  I tried to up-vote your answer but the system says I don't have enough "reputation", but it's recorded my attempt.

Comment: Thanks @johnb for that feedback. I'm energised to go help others although I'm by no means an expert in all this, just trying to offer my thoughts / lend a hand.